# R replace all instances of a pattern from a list A with instances from list C by matching A with list B

Tags: r, list, replace

I have three lists of country names.

```
orig_list <- c("MURICA","uSa","Ger","Gerrmany",...) #[LONG, about 15000 entries]
unique_spellings <- c("MURICA","uSa","Ger","Gerrmany") #[600 entries]
norm_spellings <- c("USA","USA","Germany","Germany") #[600 entries]
```

So the idea is that I want the entries in the original list be replaced by the corresponding normed spellings. Each unique spelling from orig_list is represented in unique_list and the normed spellings can be found at the same index in norm_spellings.

In a related thread (which I cannot find again for the life of me, suggested using setNames for a similar task, like

```
map = setNames(norm_spellings, unique_spellings)
orig_list  = map[orig_list]
```

works almost, but produces a lot of NAs for some reason. Is there a clever way to do it without multiple for loops?

Comment: You could try `norm_spellings[match(orig_list, unique_spellings)]`

Comment: Can you show your desired output and provide an example when your code doesn't work?